# Android multi language support - alternative to adding multiple values folder

Tags: android, multilingual

I want my current application to be localized. When I was going through the topic the method I found was to add multiple values folder with the country code as postfix. But in my app I need to consider many languages (say about more than 100).I guess it will not be that good to create that much values folder.How can I achieve this. I have seen a similar ques in stackoverflow. But I couldn't find a solution from that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not multiple values folder? You have to translate each string anyway.

Comment: Check out translation APIs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 2 ways,

1. By default way by having several strings XML inside values for language.But it will only change language with locale of your phone, Like your change your device's language from English to Chinese and vice-versa.  The problem with this approach is suppose you want to support any local language or any language which is not provided by your phone, in that case your stings will not work. It is dependent on your system,as when language change of your android system your app will change its too.
2. By using file system, either normal file or a .csv file, In this approach you have to add .csv files inside raw folder in res folder in android for every language you support.You have to load a language csv file with default, and when user select a language you make it as default.The only problem with this approach is that every time you have to load the list when application is launched(onCreate). You can use this for changing the language inside your application. When locale change your application language will not get changed.

Choose according to your requirements.

Comment: let me check it